# How to import GPU.js?

Tags: javascript, gpu

I'm trying to use GPU.js in Vue. I don't get how I have to import it though.
I'm trying this right now:

```
import * as GPU from "gpu.js";
```

If I do it this way I can console.log the the object using the this keyword in my component.

I can't instantiate it tho, I don't know how to do this in my Vue component:

```
  const gpu = new GPU();
```

I get this error message

```
GPU is not defined
```

How can I properly import GPU.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import { GPU } from "gpu.js";
const gpu = new GPU();
```

or like you did

```
import * as GPU from "gpu.js";
const gpu = new GPU.GPU();
```

The library doesn't just export a constructor. Maybe the docs should be improved ;)